# two lines are created in one cell

Tags: sql, oracle

I have an sql code that is retreiving a row with more than one line, Is there a way to make it combine those two lines into one line.

```
select revertrsn  from LN08PENm where aano in(754,870,1136,1138,1139,1140)
```

the data coming in the row that I am retreiving is like this:

> As per Mohammad Sulaiman's approval
>
> by mail date 07/04/2009

And I want it to be in one line like this:

> As per Mohammad Sulaiman's approval by mail date 07/04/2009

Answer (score 2):

You could replace the newline character `\n` or `char(10)` with a whitespace character  .
For example:

```
select replace(revertrsn,chr(10),' ') as only_one_line
  from LN08PENm 
 where aano in(754,870,1136,1138,1139,1140)
```

Note that the throw-a-line instruction varies across operating systems.  On Windows you would need to check for a carriage return followed by a newline: `chr(13)||chr(10)`.  Confusingly, the OS we need to woory about is the OS which loaded the data, not the OS we're using for output.

Comment: OK, but can I do it using sql plus.

Comment: @sofian - this is not PL/SQL: both REPLACE() and CHR() [note original had typo] are Oracle SQL built-ins (and have been for decades).  You cannot do this in SQL*Plus because string manipulation is beyond its powers.

Comment: What I wrote is SQL for the MySQL server. Give me 5 minutes and I'll edit the answer to include Oracle SQL

Answer (score 1):

A good approach to cleaning up this sort of mess is just to replace non-printing control codes in general.

```
update tab
set    col =  regexp_replace(col,'[:cntrl:]','')
where  col != regexp_replace(col,'[:cntrl:]','')
```

Comment: Replacing a line-throw with NULL may corrupt the data, for instance if it's an address like this: `1234 Main Street\nSheboygan` (and I have seen stuff like that, all too often). So a space may be safer. Except that in some circumstances that would also be undesirable. Data cleansing (as I know you know) is a task fraught with difficulties.

Comment: Yes, that's true. Replacing with a space if the control character (or set of consecutive control characters) does not have white space on either side of it would be more clear.